# Is it possible to activate iMessages without phone number on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I have iPhone with a SIM card and a phone number. I would like to activate iMessages, but only for my Apple ID's e-mail address, and not phone numbebr. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84759/removing-phone-number-from-imessage